# Cannot require Zend/Config/Ini when Zend is in the include path?

Tags: php, zend-framework

When I try this:

```
require_once 'Zend/Config/Ini.php';
```

I am getting this error in my Zend Framework application:

```
Warning: require_once(Zend/Config/Ini.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /path/to/functions.php on line 408
```

When I print out my include path, it is:

```
string(101) "/path/to/www/app/modules/:/path/to/www/lib/:.:/usr/local/share/pear"
```

I have ZF library in the /path/to/www/lib/ folder, so wtf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved the problem:

```
chmod -R 755 /path/to/www/lib
```

Blimey!